# React + TypeScript: npm run build not picking up tsconfig.json file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, tsconfig

I have created a React + TypeScript project using this command:

`npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

By default it created a `tsconfig.json` file my root folder. This tsconfig is pretty basic.

The problem comes when I try to understand how all this is working. It seems enough to run `npm run build` to have all my ts and tsx files in `src` to be compiled in `build` folder. But when I apply a change in `tsconfig.json`, like adding not existing files to `exclude` section, or removing `src` from the `include`, is like `tsconfig.json` doesn't get picked up. Even a broken tsconfig.json file doesn't procude any error.

Some other strange behavior: I tried changing the `outDir` option to `myfolder` as my files were placed under `build`. TypeScript docs state:

`If not specified, .js files will be emitted in the same directory as the .ts files they were generated from:`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outDir

Well files keep getting placed under `build`. Not even the same dire the tsx files, as the docs state.

The reason why I'm manipulating the tsconfig.json file is because I'm using Amplify from AWS and I would need to add some custom actions to the build.

Some data about my setup:

`node -v v19.3.0`

`npm -v 9.2.0`

`npm list`

````
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.16.5
├── @testing-library/react@13.4.0
├── @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0
├── @types/jest@27.5.2
├── @types/node@16.18.16
├── @types/react-dom@18.0.11
├── @types/react@18.0.28
├── antd@5.3.1
├── aws-amplify@5.0.19
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react-scripts@5.0.1
├── react@18.2.0
├── typescript@4.9.5
└── web-vitals@2.1.4```
````

Comment: `react-scripts build` uses webpack (not tsc) to convert the files into js. `tsc` is only used for type checking, not conversion to js. You can also see `noEmit` in the tsconfig.json, so `npx tsc` will just check the types with tsconfig but produces no build.

Comment: I find it hard to configure webpack etc, unless I `npm run eject` to get the config files. However, `eject`ing will change the structure dramatically, and it's permanent unless you have a version control.